# Extracting data from SQLite database (Android)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Im able to write data to a the database in the main activity but im having problems reading and displaying the data in a different activity. I'm using a SQLHelperDatabase class with a 'addData' method (which works fine according to the debugger) and a showData method (and this is where the problem lies). After entering data in the main activity i want to be able to press the send message button and the data to be displayed on the new activity. Ive been stuck on this for a week now and i been searching the WWW and every tutorial says that my code should work. Please can someone help me get to the bottom of this frustrating ordeal.

```
package com.doors.waynderful.myapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
DatabaseHelper db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        Cursor cursor = db.showData();
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        String nam = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.THE_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME));

        if (!cursor.isClosed()){
            cursor.close();
        }




    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(nam);

   setContentView(textView);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_display_message, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
}
```

Below is the SQLHelperDatabase.

```
package com.doors.waynderful.myapp;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
public static final String THE_DATABASE = "theDatabase";
public static final String THE_TABLE = "infoTable";
public static final String THE_TABLE_COLUMN_ID = "id";
public static final String THE_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME = "name";
public static final String THE_TABLE_COLUMN_DETAILS = "details";

DatabaseHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context,THE_DATABASE, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " +THE_TABLE+"(id integer primary key, name text,     details text) ");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + THE_TABLE + "");

    onCreate(db);
}

public void addData(String nameIn, String detailsIn)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues data = new ContentValues();

    data.put("name", nameIn);
    data.put("details", detailsIn);

    db.insert(THE_TABLE,null,data);

    }

    public Cursor showData()
    {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor;
    cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from "+THE_TABLE+"", null);
    return cursor;

    }
}
```

Below is the MainActivity

```
package com.doors.waynderful.myapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.doors.waynderful.myapp.MESSAGE";
DatabaseHelper myDb;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void sendMessage(View view){
    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);


    Intent intent = new Intent(this,DisplayMessageActivity.class);

    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
    EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_details);

    String name = editText.getText().toString();
    String details = editText1.getText().toString();

    myDb.addData(name, details);
    //intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,message);

   startActivity(intent);

}
}
```

LOGCAT shows

03-31 09:40:31.100    1351-1351/com.doors.waynderful.myapp E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) no such table: infoTable

Comment: have you ever created any table?

Comment: code now reflects the tables being added. sorry my bad.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you think that you must necessarily have a row in the database with an id = 1

If you want to find a row with a specific name, use a sql statement that selects the row with that name.

If you want to list all rows, then select all rows.

But inserting a row, and then assuming that you know it's id simply isn't going to work.

Also, you should use your (currently commented out) code that uses a layout instead of creating a new text view and setting that as the content view.

Finally, you don't seem to have any code that actually creates the table in the database?

Comment: i did assume that if data was added to a table it would automatically be assigned with the index 1 (bad assumption perhaps). I have recently updated the the code to show the table being created, i mistakenly missed it out when composing the post.

Comment: Am I not creating the table in the way?